# Pass a field in required when a radio button value is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

Basically I am using react hook form, I want to trigger a field to be required if I click a specific value in my radio button. Obviously it is dynamic so there could be anything in the radio button. I want to get the selected value from the radio and then depending on the selected value trigger another field to be required.

I have no clue on how to do it with react hook form; mayne someone has come across the same issue and have an example to show me

Answer (score 0):

you can use `validate function` from react hook form

```
<input
      {...register("test", {
        validate:{ required: value => getValues().radioBtn }
      })}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

1. trigger a function once your desired radio button was clicked.
2. get hew value [How to get value from radio button](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button-using-javascript/)
3. set the attribute 'required' to true ['Required' attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

let me know if that helps you